# Should TypeScript definition files be included in _references.js?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, typescript

Say, I include a Nuget package [jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/), should it be added as a reference to `Scripts/_references.js`? And if so, should it be possible to remove [jQuery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery/), or specifically, say, `jquery-2.1.1.js` file from the Scipts directory? That is to say, would I have a need for plain .js nuget packages when a TypeScript one is available?

In a broader context, I'm thinking how this process works or what could be the preferred way of working or what shoud work in Visual Studio 2013 with the latest updates. Many of the blog posts and tutorials I find elaborate on methods before TypeScript tooling was included within Visual Studio.

<edit: It looks like that one could let a lot of other resources with Javascript libraries, like pictures and css files. So, it would seem, both the `.js` file and optionally a `d.ts` files would be needed. But should the `d.ts` file be included in `_references.js` or perhaps both the `.js` and `d.ts` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Say, I include a Nuget package jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped, should it be added as a reference to Scripts/_references.js?

As long as you have the `jquery.d.ts` in your project that will be good enough. The definition file doesn't end up in any compiled javascript output (see [using _references.ts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/12/05/announcing-typescript-0-9-5.aspx) for more detail).

Edit: Just to reiterate since I just realized you're talking about `_references.js` and not `_references.ts`... adding the `.js` file and `.d.ts` is not necessary for intellisense. Having `jquery.d.ts` in the project is good enough for intellisense in VS 2013.

> Should it be possible to remove jQuery, or specifically, say, jquery-2.1.1.js file from the Scipts directory?

No, don't remove your `jquery.js` file. The nuget package from DefinitelyTyped is simply a **definition** file. Definition files offer no functionality and simply [describe the shape of a library](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Writing%20Definition%20(.d.ts)%20Files). It allows people to use existing JavaScript libraries with the added benefit of type constraints—without having to rewrite and maintain the library separately in TypeScript.

For example, say I have a JavaScript library that contains the following code:

```
function myAlert(text) {
    alert(text);
}
```

A definition file that describes this JavaScript library might look like this:

```
declare var myAlert: (text: string) => void;
```

As you can see, there's no functionality in my definition file and so both are required for using my JS library in TypeScript (take note that only the JS file is required in production code because that is the one that the browser will execute).

Comment: Thanks! This was rather enlightening. I was aware of the ``.ts`` files. For some reason I didn't connect (or open) the ``.d.ts`` files and was a bit in loss with all the conventions.

Comment: @Veksi that's cool, everyone learns it at some point and I'm glad it helped. I think the documentation isn't very clear about it.