# Typescript: Generated javascript files are not visible within Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

How can I view the generated javascript files with the typescript file in Visual studio 2015?

Note: Javascripts files generated are present in the File Explorer but are not visible in the solution explorer.

Moreover, I tried to add the _references.ts file in the root directory of the project however, there was no 'Update Typescript references' as available in javascript's _references.js file

Comment: Check out the [preview](http://vswebessentials.com/features/typescript#preview) functionality in web essentials.

Comment: @David Feature has been be removed. Might come back in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

In **solution explorer** exist button with name **show all files**, just click it and you would see all files in the project folder

[image: How to show all files in the solution explorer]

### See also

- [Hidden Project Files in Solution Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4afxey9h(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Oh! But why are generated javascript files not visible by default? Moreover, is there a way to auto add references to _references.ts file just like we do with _references.js file? Is there a need to do this or _references.js would take care of it?

Comment: because VS does know anything about your generated files, also it may cause error, because if you compile d.ts file the IntelliSense would tell you that in the project has already existed class or function with the same name, that is why this files does not included to project by default

Comment: Got it, the link in the answer cleared my doubt. However, I still have one more doubt: How can we auto reference all the typescript files in the _references.ts file. I see no option to auto-sync or update references like we have in _references.js

Comment: What do you mean under *auto-reference*? 
Usually, I create one file, where manually store all references to project files, intellisense take care in this case about in what order modules should compiled in result files

Comment: There is an auto-sync option provided for _references.js file that would search for all javascript files and reference them automatically. Is there something similar available for _references.ts?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have never deal with this feature, try to read [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183927/should-typescript-definition-files-be-included-in-references-js) may be it would help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90808/discussion-between-oleg-dokuka-and-shyamal-parikh).